# android. kotlin, the coverage test is failing on lateinit var member

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, code-coverage, kotlintest

in android kotlin class it has a `lateinit var` member. The coverage test is failing on the function referring to it.

The simplified class here:

```
open class TestC constructor(context: Context) {

    private lateinit var mModule: NotificationModule
    protected fun setModule(module: NotificationModule) {
        mModule = module
    }

    protected fun getModule(): NotificationModule {
        return mModule
    }

    fun doSomething() {
        if (mModule.pushToken == null) {
            System.out.println(("+++ 111"))
        } else {
            System.out.println(("+++ 222"))
        }
    }

    @JvmField
    protected var mContext: Context

    init {
        mContext = context
    }
}

class NotificationModule {
    private var _token: String? = null
    val pushToken: String?
        get() = _token

    protected open fun setPushToken(pushToken: String) {
        _token = pushToken
    }
}
```

the coverage test failed on `getModule()`, and `doSomething()`.

the decompiled code shows it will check `null` on the non-null member, so that the coverage test reports the branch is missed :

```
@NotNull
   protected final NotificationModule getModule() {
      NotificationModule var10000 = this.mModule;
      if (var10000 == null) {  //<== never null
         Intrinsics.throwUninitializedPropertyAccessException("mModule");
      }

      return var10000;
   }

   public final void doSomething() {
      NotificationModule var10000 = this.mModule;
      if (var10000 == null) { //<== never null
         Intrinsics.throwUninitializedPropertyAccessException("mModule");
      }

      if (var10000.getPushToken() == null) {
         System.out.println("+++ 111");
      } else {
         System.out.println("+++ 222");
      }

   }
```

How to test those hidden code branches?

**Update:**

It is the test missed a case that should test access the field before init-ed it.

closing this question.

Comment: How about just don't be obsessed with coverage?

Comment: thank you for sharing you opinion but it is required here.

Answer (score 0):

oh remove the lateinit

```
private var mModule: NotificationModule? = null
protected fun getModule(): NotificationModule {
        return mModule?: throw UninitializedPropertyAccessException("!!! mModule has not been initialized") //mimic lateinit behavior
    
}
```